# Publish messages using Java WebSocket client to Apache Apollo topic

Tags: java, websocket, apollo

I've setup an instance of Apache Apollo and I have a JavaScript client connected and subscribed to "chat.general". This shows up as a "topic" in the Apollo [web] Console.

I'm trying to use a Java client to publish a message to that topic so my JavaScript client can receive it. I tried using netty-tools without luck, I was able to connect to apollo and then send a message but it never seemed to get to Apollo and I never received any errors.

Now I'm trying to use the [async-http-client](http://jfarcand.wordpress.com/2011/12/21/writing-websocket-clients-using-asynchttpclient/) with the same problem, I can connect but my message doesn't seem to get to the chat.general topic.

I am setting up the "WebSocket" using the async-http-client (linked to above) using the following URI:

```
ws://admin:password@localhost:61623/topic/chat.general
```

Has anyone else had luck publishing to a WebSocket topic on Apache Apollo from a Java client? If so, how :)

Answer (score 1):

Somehow I got lost and thought I needed to connect via WebSocket (from Java) to send a message to the topic, wrong!

I just connected to the JMS topic as I normally might, published a message and wah-lah, the JS client sees it!

Answer (score 1):

I successfully used STOMP as a publish/subscribe protocol on top of the WebSocket protocol, using the Apollo broker.

As a Java producer and consumer I used Stampy (http://mrstampy.github.io/Stampy/), but if you need a java script consumer you can have a look at stomp.js (https://github.com/jmesnil/stomp-websocket/).

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you have used Stampy to implement Stomp over WS?? I've tried in all ways, but i'm not been able to get it works.. I'm working in java SE environment